# Unit root test for ARIMA models

Tags: arima, polynomial, unit-root

I have a slight confusion regarding **seasonal** models and which polynomial to use for conducting unit root tests.

Given a model:

$\phi(B)\Phi(B^s)\Delta^d\Delta^D_S X_t = \theta(B)\Theta(B^s)\epsilon    $

When I compute the roots for unit root tests, **which polynomials do I calculate the roots of**?

Only the basic $AR(p)$ and $MA(q)$ compononents? That is, do I use just $\phi(B)$ and $\theta(B)$?

Or instead, do I also include the seasonal polynomials as well? 
ie, compute the roots by solving for $\phi(B)\Phi(B^s)$ and $\theta(B)\Theta(B^s)$ ?